# Purpose of aspnet_isapi.dll hosted in w3wp - IIS 6?

Tags: iis-6, asp.net

What is the purpose of the ASP.NET ISAPI extension **aspnet_isapi.dll** that is hosted in the worker process **w3wp.exe** in IIS 6.0 ?

In IIS 5.0, I understood that this ISAPI extension was responsible for handling all asp.net requests (aspx etc). It was loaded in the IIS process and was responsible for sending the requests to the ASP.NET worker process **aspnet_wp.exe** using named pipes.

With IIS 6.0, the requests reach w3wp.exe directly from the kernel and the ISAPI extension is later loaded in this worker process.

In the MSDN article (IIS 6.0) [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302436.aspx) is says *Aspnet_isapi.dll - Queues requests for processing by the managed code ASP.NET engine and performs health monitoring.*

This confuses me.

- Aren't the requests already queues @ the kernel level ?
- Isn't aspnet_isapi.dll unmanged code ? i.e. a regular win32 dll ? And isn't w3wp managed code ?

I am totally lost :-|

Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479328.aspx), if using IIS6 process model, aspnet_isapi.dll isn't used to queue requests, but it *is* responsible for initialising the the CLR.

> When the request arrives, IIS examines
>   the resource type and calls into the
>   ASP.NET ISAPI extension. If the
>   default process model is enabled,
>   aspnet_isapi queues the request and
>   assigns it to the worker process. Any
>   request data is sent through
>   asynchronous I/O. If the IIS 6 process
>   model is enabled, the request is
>   automatically queued to the worker
>   process (w3wp.exe) handling the IIS
>   application pool to which the
>   application belongs. The IIS 6 worker
>   process doesn't know anything about
>   ASP.NET and managed code. It is
>   limited to processing the *.aspx
>   extension and loading the aspnet_isapi
>   module. When the ASP.NET ISAPI works
>   under the IIS 6 process model, it
>   behaves differently and just loads the
>   CLR in the context of the w3wp.exe
>   worker process.

Comment: No problem. If this answers your question, would you mind "accepting" the answer?

Comment: Sure ! The article is definitely a find !